# Configuration of search shortcut from Application launcher KDE

Tags: fedora, configuration, kde, plasma, launcher

Here is my configuration:

```
OS: Fedora release 30 (Thirty) x86_64 
Host: Latitude 5580 
Kernel: 5.1.7-300.fc30.x86_64 
Uptime: 1 hour, 58 mins 
Shell: zsh 5.7.1 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2], Default [GTK3] 
Icons: breeze [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2], breeze [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i5-6440HQ (4) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
Memory: 3516MiB / 7594MiB
```

I am using the Application Launcher and I would like to configure it in the following way:

- if I type a command like "!w chalpin" in the search entry of the Application Launcher, I would like that my internet browser opens and gives wikipedia results for the "chaplin" request.

The same for other website like youtube,stack exchange...

Comment: `neofetch --color_blocks off --backend off` will leave out the ascii art, if you wish.

Comment: Are you talking about the default launcher? I can't imagine this is easy to configure/hack. What about alternative launchers?

Comment: yes it should be the default Applications Launcher. I thougght also to Plasma Search but I can't figure out a way to configure it

Comment: Why don't you just use *krunner*? Enable web shortcuts in *System Settings > Shortcuts > Web Shortcuts* where the default for wikipedia is `wp` and enable it as well in *System Settings > Search > Plasma Search*. Then you can press `Alt+spacebar` to bring up krunner, type `wp:chaplin` and press enter. Works for me in Fedora 30 KDE spin.

Comment: good point, problem solved